# How to get product details and associate category names in only one query in Magento

Tags: php, magento, model, categories, product

I want to run only one query $prod_details and then run a loop that gives me some product detials, but i am failing to get the category name.

(i don't want to run another query inside the loop to get the category name)

This is the code i'm using:

```
$prod_details = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addWebsiteFilter($web_id)->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $prod_details->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $prod_details->distinct(true)
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', null, 'product_id = entity_id','{{table}}.category_id', 'inner')->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category_id))
    ->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1','left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 0));

foreach ($prod_details as $product) {

        $product_data["pid"]=$product->getId();
        $product_data['qty']=$product->getQty();...
    $product_data['category'] = $product->getParentCategory()->getName();
```

I can get the produt ID and quantity fine but the category name will not populate, i don't want to have to run `$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` inside the loop to get the category name.

When i change the values on category 'attributetofiler' either the whole query doesn't run or i get an error or it runs without category name. 
Can anyone spot any errors? Thanks